# Aproximate values of holomorph function by identity principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I have two sequences of complex numbers $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_n \to a$, and $b_n \to b$, and I construct a complex function $f$ by saying $f(a_n) = b_n$ and $f(a) = b$.

By the identity principle, if I understand, if $f$ can be extended analytically, there is only one way to do so.  Say it can be exteded analytically to $z \in \mathbb{C}$, how can I calculate $f(z)$?  I mean I would like to aproximate with an algorithm the value of $f(z)$ just to the firsts decimal places, is there a way to do so?

Comment: An example where you don't need an approximation: The $\Gamma$ function can be extended into the numbers with negative real parts with $$\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+n)}{z(z+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot (z+n-1)}$$ so you are able to compute $\Gamma(-1/2)$ directly for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: I checked with wolframalpha and $\Gamma(-1/2) = -2\sqrt{\pi}$.  Other than that I didn't understand what you tried to say, how would I get that value with that formula?